# Remove Pages windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, memory, navigation, windows-phone

I have a big project where my application keeps retaining a page which I navigated away from. The page is only used minimal, and have a lot of graphics, I therefore want it to be completely removed from memory.

I therefore used the following

```
 NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

Using the profiler I saw that, the above snippet made sure that I would only have 1 instance of the page. But as it is heavy with graphics I still want it to be completely removed from memory, i.e. no instances in the profiler.

In my big application I tried to unsubscribe to all events, introduce dispose/finalize and calling GC, it helped some but the instance still existed.

To exclude any stupid errors, I have made [this small sample](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kyt4q9z0en4vsno/AABHAo881m4mzz_k3iJrotnta?dl=0). Only Navigating between two dumb pages with a memory popup checker. But still 1-2 instances of the pages still exists. Is there anyway to force the removal of pages such that nothing of it is stored in memory?

I've added:

```
            while (App.RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry() != null) ;
```

To the OnNavigated to, and it removes all the pages except the first page I start on. I've used the debug analysis toolkit, and can see that no matter what the first page I start on does not get removed, when I navigate away from it.

Comment: Maybe look at http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/

Comment: Does not seem to work

Comment: Wonder if you have tried setting that page's `NavigationCacheMode` to `Disabled`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WP Silverlight runtime will keep up to three pages in memory, even after being removed from the backstack. The reason for this behavior is still unclear to me, but I've found a (ugly) workaround: http://blogs.codes-sources.com/kookiz/archive/2013/11/11/wpdev-give-that-memory-back.aspx

Basically, override the `OnNavigatedTo` handler of your page, and force a garbage collection three times, separated by calls to the dispatcher:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            });
        });
    });
}
```

As crazy as it sounds, it works.

---

In your case, you have another problem. You are keeping the page alive with your popup. Let me explain:

In the `CreatePopups` method, you create the popup and add it to the grid of the starting page.
In the popup, you start a timer to call `UpdateMemoryInfo` at regular interval.
The timer is kept alive by the .NET runtime until it's stopped. The timer keeps a reference on your popup because you're using an instance method as event handler. Your popup is keeping a reference to the grid through the `Parent` property. The grid is keeping a reference to the page through its own `Parent` property. So you just made your page immortal, for as long as your timer is ticking.
To prove that the issue is there, just make the `UpdateMemoryInfo` method static (and remove all the UI updating code there's inside). Since the event handler is now static, the timer won't hold a reference to instance of popup. Run the profiler, and you'll see that the instance of the page is now reclaimed by the garbage collector as you expect.

---

Of course, it supposes that your pages have been removed from the back stack. Either by pressing the back key or calling the `NavigationService.GoBack()` method, or by manually removing them using `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` (in case you only use forward navigation)

Comment: Does not seem to work, when we try to implement it. Even on the dummy app included in the question.

Per your blog post, it seems that you only navigate out, and use backkey to go back. But in this application the backkey is not necessarily used. More likely, navigationservice between the different pages.

Have you tried it by only using NavigationService and not the backkey. The backkey in our implementation is used as quit.

Comment: I have the same comments as JTIM

Comment: @JonasN89 Sorry, just noticed there's another issue in your repro project. See my edit.

Comment: Same for @JTIM I guess

Comment: @KooKiz we missed `UpdateMemoryInfo` :/ But of course as you say it keeps a reference. But just a clarifying comment/question, since we often navigate using the navigationService and not the goback button, this code snippet ´RemoveBackEntry()´, should still be used in connection with your code? As this would ensure that it is not referenced in the navigation stack, and therefore can be collected ?
Secondly for the `UpdateMemoryInfo` how do we get it to update the memory without a UI updater, just introduce a button for updating or?
I will try and go through it tonight! Thx for your follow up.

Comment: @JTIM Even after using `RemoveBackEntry`, the runtime keeps up to three pages in memory (whether you removed them from the backstack using `GoBack`, the back button, or `RemoveBackEntry` doesn't change much). Using the trick I gave isn't mandatory, but can give some relief if your application easily runs out of memory

Comment: @KooKiz yes that is true, but if you do not use `RemoveBackEntry`, it will still have the reference. It is just so you can update your answer to be completely correct. One needs to use `RemoveBackEntry` if one navigates using navigationService and not the backkey. Then you have to use `RemoveBackEntry` to remove the pages from the navigation stack. Then they are in the memory as was the issue, of our comment, and then your code snippet works.

Comment: @JTIM Indeed, in case you only do forward navigation, then the pages will remain in the backstack until `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry` is called. Edited my answer.