# Deleting project/pages/usercontrols from memory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, memory, windows-phone

I have made a windows phone app, that unfortunately has some memory leak, because pages are not removed correctly. This was solved by using the answer:

[Remove Pages windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393799/remove-pages-windows-phone)
Stating:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
while (App.RootFrame.RemoveBackEntry() != null) ; //line if you navigate without backkey
base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        });
    });
```

}

This removed the page references from the profiler. But the memory still increased some upon navigation. And it was not obvious where the increased memory came from.
I therefore Tried introducing a blank project and navigated to that as a star navigation, Illustrated as:

[image]

This made removed upwards of 20 mb, of visuals and other elements. So this was a major step. I therefore wanted to split functionality out onto different projects as to remove any ties between the different functionalities and keep low memory usage. This ended up with the following structure:

- WebService
- MainProject
- SecondaryProject
- PortableLibrary

I share models between all projects using the Portable Library. 
This influenced that upon every navigation to a new project everything is cleared in the old project, i.e. only one element of each item exist, major memory improvement. But still some memory leak, however bounded, meaning only a certain increase in memory.
But where comes the memory from? Going back into the profiler:

[image]

This shows that the pages are not removed specifically, all elements *.view.* would have been removed by the code in the configuration of all pages being in one project. However the memory leak is similar.

**The Question**

1. How do I remove pages and elements from a different project within
   the same solution?
2. How do I remove a project from memory?

There is not information shared between the two projects, other than they both can create a version of `LibraryOfModels`. Therefore no events, variables or references is shared across the project borders. 
But for the life of me I cannot get it removed from memory. I want to remove them from the memory, as my code snippet in the top does, IF the navigation was only within one project. The issue exists because of the navigation is spread out on two projects. But it has some memory benefits in other areas, which is why I want this structure.

Hope somebody can help. 
Thx!

**Additional tests**

I have tried making all pages usercontrols such that I could avoid navigation. But recreating them a couple of times gav a steady leak of 1-2 Mb. The project idea is therefore still best as there is a bound. But still no solution of getting it removed.

Still hoping for the knight with the shiney keyboard ;)

Comment: Are you sure there are no events attached?

Comment: Yeah the two pages are divided out in two different projects, and have no relation. Since they cannot reference the same elements, because of the split out in different projects. I am not saying that there does not exist events inside the different projects, Therefore it would be interesting to remove the entire project, as it would not have any runtime issues, since these references would never be called.
You think that the internal reference of the projects would keep it alive without any references pointing out of the project?

Comment: I think when you are loading pages you can try singleton pattern

Comment: @JestinC.I I have never used it, but a quick read around gives me the following understanding. You can use `Singleton` to enforce the creation of only one instance of objects, correct?
If so it will not help me, as there exists only one element of each instance. I want to remove them from the memory, as my code snippet in the top can do, IF the navigation is only within one project. The issue exists because of the navigation is spread out on two projects. But it has some memory benefits in other areas, which is why I want this structure.

Comment: I am not clear about what you said. Are you running two projects at the sametime?

Comment: In the solution I have 2 projects of type wp silverlight. 
In "build configuration" they are both set to build, but only "MainProject" to deploy. Such that the deployed application has an internal "extra" project. This "extra" project has a page, with several views and viewmodels. Therefore the navigation to this page is done like `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/project;component/View/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`. This split means there is no references events or anything moving across the project borders. And When I navigate away from the "extra" project I want to clean memory.

Comment: Maybe you should make sure, that no threads/tasks/timers keep reference to your views/viewmodels? Just in case some interesting articles about memory leaks: [Memory Leaks in WPF applications](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html), [Managing Memory in Windows Store Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721593.aspx)

Comment: @WojciechKulik thx for your reference. I am quite sure that no reference exists also based on your link seems like events should be removed when page is removed. I can verify that only one element exists no timers or threads or tasks and no variables across because they are in individual projects and info is only shared via resource manager or navigationpath extended with variables. Seems odd, I think my next idea is to try and upgrade the entire solution to wp8.1 and see if some benefits arrive there. But I will look more on the link you supplied ! Thank you

Comment: One more thing crossed my mind: do you use some 3rd party controls/libraries, Image, [LongListSelector](https://cbailiss.wordpress.com/2014/01/24/windows-phone-8-longlistselector-memory-leak/), FlipView or WebView (because they have some issues with memory managment)? I guess it will be hard to find the problem without any sample project. Are you able to prepare something like this, where reproducing this issue will be possible? If it doesn't occur on empty project with the same architecture, then there is some issue in code/controls.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can make the object singleton and you can clear the values of objects manually when accordingly.
Please refer the link below
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: As stated in the above comments I do not see how this should solve the issue. As far as I can read from your link, it will force only one element of an object. But referring to the image in my question you can see that there is only one instance of the objects. So how will this help me remove existing pages from memory? The benefit of only having one in memory is already achieved because of the pages being in different projects, and I remove the backstack, this influences that the pages will be remade upon every navigation (desired), but some of the pages still exists, how can singleton help?

Comment: Singleton will not help. the only thing is that there is only instance in memory. can u please explain, how can singleton help?

Comment: @jobyjames85: singleton only creates one object at a time ,so object handling will be easy and if in some scenarios if singleton not used and garbage collector not handled properly there will be memory leaks for this type of large programs.

Answer (score 0):

Find all disposable graphics/IO, make sure that disposed them, (after you finished to use them).
The all such objects inheriting from IDispose interface.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of third party controls/libraries, Image, LongListSelector, FlipView or WebView, because they have some issues with memory management.

You should make sure, that no threads/tasks/timers keep reference to your Views/ViewModels.

There are two interesting articles about memory leaks:

- [Memory Leaks in WPF applications](http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.com/2010/05/memory-leaks-in-wpf-applications.html)
- [Managing Memory in Windows Store Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj721593.aspx)

I guess it will be hard to find the root cause without any sample project. If it doesn't occur in empty project with the same architecture, then there is some issue in your code.