# Windows Phone 8.1: NavigationCache not required while forwarding the page

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Windows 8.1 Universal App. I have three pages: Page 1,Page 2 and Page 3.
I enabled the NavigationCacheMode inside the constructor on Page 2.

When i am navigating from 
Page 1(Login page) -> Page 2(Search screen) - > Page 3(Result Screen).

On Search screen, I am searching emails through API and then navigate to Result Page.When i press back button on result Page, my screen navigates to Page 2(Search Screen) with previous state which is okay.

But when I am logging out from Page 3(Result Page) itself then my screen would get navigates to Page 1(Login Page). and after then i again login then it would navigates to Page 2(Search Screen) but this time previous cached state of page are also there that should i don't want.

Means when i am navigating to fresh instantiated page, it captures the cached content from previous state when i was visited last time.

Suggest me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When navigating to the second page, can you check NavigationEventArgs.NavigationMode in OnNavigatedTo override? If it's "New" you can clear the search term and search results

Comment: Yes i am checking Navigation mode. You mean to say that every time i have to clear all the objects manually again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, you would like to clear the page cache when a user logged out. If so, we can try to reset the cache by setting the [Frame.CacheSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.cachesize.aspx) to 0 first and set back to the original value. There is a good example in [Andreas Hammer's blog](http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/) as below:

```
var cacheSize = ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize;
((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = 0;
((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = cacheSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose you to look at this [Remove Pages windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393799/remove-pages-windows-phone) where you can learn to remove pages. Further look into overriding the backkey event.